# How to write script(inline) in script_score including some custom logic with if conditions on doc[] element?

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch

I am a novice with elastic search and while writing script_score I am facing parse exception saying 'expected field name but got [START_ARRAY]'

Here is the mapping:

```
PUT toadb
{
   "mappings":{
      "keywords":{
         "properties":{
            "Name":{"type":"string","analyzer": "simple"},
            "Type":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
            "Id":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
            "Boosting Field":{"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"}
            }
        },
      "businesses":{
          "properties": {
          "Name":{"type":"string","analyzer": "simple"},
          "Type":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
          "Id":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
          "Business_seq":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
          "Status":{"type":"string","index": "not_analyzed"},
          "System_rating":{"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"},
          "System_rating_weight":{"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"},
          "Position":{ "type":"geo_point","lat_lon": true},
          "Display Pic":{"type": "string","index": "not_analyzed"},
          "Boosting Field":{"type" : "integer", "store" : "yes"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the query I am trying to execute:

```
 GET /toadb/_search
        {
            "query":{
            "function_score" : {
                 "query" : {
                       "multi_match" : {
                                "query":    "Restaurant", 
                                "fields": [ "Name"],"fuzziness":1 
                                }},

                       "script_score":
                        {
                           "script":"if(doc['Status'] && doc['Status']=='A'){ _score+ (doc['Boosting Field'].value);}"
                        }
            },
            "size":10
         }
}
```

Please provide sample examples if any (Already referred to elasticsearch documentation)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have mistakenly placed the `size` option in your query. In your example, you have added it as a field next to the `function_score` query. Instead, it belongs as a sibling to the root `query` object.

Try this:

```
GET /toadb/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Restaurant",
          "fields": [
            "Name"
          ],
          "fuzziness": 1
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "if(doc['Status'] && doc['Status']=='A'){ _score+ (doc['Boosting Field'].value);}"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 10
}
```

Have a look at the documentation for the [request body search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html).